# Equivalent of "touch" relationship in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data

Anyone who is familiar with ActiveRecord probably knows about the "touch" relationship attribute.

> If you set the :touch option to :true, then the updated_at or
>   updated_on timestamp on the associated object will be set to the
>   current time whenever this object is saved or destroyed:

I'm trying to do the same thing in Core Data.  Essentially I have a top level object which populates a table view backed with an `NSFetchedResultsController` for change tracking and I'm trying to mark the object as being updated when one of its children is updated.  Is anyone aware of a built in methodology for this?  I can put something together but I'm trying to see if anyone knows of a way to do this without doing something custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no built-in functionality like that.

Whenever you modify a MOM, you gotta have & set a manual property.
You CAN do 'automate' this using willSave of the ManagedObject subclass you have

====

```
func willSave() -> {
    let now = NSDate()
    if(!self.lastSaveData || self.lastSaveData!.isEqualToDate(now)) {
        self.lastSaveDate = now //TODO and/or notify parent ;)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was my backup plan.  I just wondered if there was a way to flag an object as "dirty" that would propagate through Core Data without needing a property to track it.  Thanks.